# How to store the reference of one ImageView in another ImageView in android?

Tags: android, caching, imageview, imagedownload

I am downloading the images from url and storing in android device, I am trying to display the   images from my android device to ImageView(all ImageView has different Id's).

My Questions is:

I am downloading the images and trying to display in ImageView but how to get the reference of one ImageView in another ImageView so that there is no need to download the same image again, if I want to display the same Image in more than one ImageView (i.e How should I display the downloaded image from my android device in more than one Image View which has unique Id ?)[image]

In the above screen the images of India and Australia are already downloaded  and displaying in ImageView but how should I display the images in another ImageView where the other matches of India and Australia are displaying , I don't want to download the same image again and again so how should I use those images in other ImageView?

Comment: `how to get the reference of one ImageView in another ImageView` **??**

Comment: `I want to display the same Image in more than one ImageView` - Just set the same image source for all the ImageViews that should have the same content. It's so easy...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Imageloader` for loading images and on `disc-caching`.
it will not download new if url is same.
For `imageLoader` go through link [ImageLiader](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

Comment: I have already done that, I am not downloading the image again if the url is same, the problem how should I use that same image in different imageViews

Comment: Ads you added view there you have to team as a model then you can put image-path value in model.
you can set then easily...

Answer (score 0):

Store image with unique_id as image path. At the time of retrieval(get image path) you will get only one image with one unique_id.

Your image path may look like `Flag_[unique_id]`. Now every time you will get same image with particular path.